# Can anyone tell me how they expanded $x^n-a^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

[image]

I am not getting *how* they factorised the $x^n-a^n$ term?

Comment: What are you not getting? The factorization is right there, on the line below the blue "Proof". Do you deny that the product of the two factors is $x^n-a^n$?

Comment: It is, but to be honest, that explanation only shows the check that the long division is correct. It doesn't really go into the division itself.

Comment: This is a high-school identity. It is derived from the factorisation: $\;1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})$ which is the basis for the sum of the geometric series, and is easily proved by induction.

Comment: @Bernard There are other ways to derive it as well.

Comment: @A---B: The high-school identity is the simplest for me. I learnt it when at the end of mid-school.

Comment: @Bernard This is my favorite identity I never miss a chance to use it.

Comment: @Bernard You can write an answer to this question.

Comment: Oh! I like the induction approach.

Comment: Could you add your effort [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147355/how-do-i-solve-e-sinx-e-sinx-4/2147358#2147358)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets do it backwards for a special case . You have the sum of powers

$$1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1}.$$

Multiply this by $x$ and you get

$$x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n.$$

You find that increasing the exponent of each term by $1$ essentially did nothing else but removing the $1$ from the beginning and adding the $x^n$ at the end. Every term in between is contained in both sums. This means we can get the second form from the first one by the following operation instead:

$$x\cdot (1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})=(1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})+(x^n-1).$$

The left side is what we already did before, the right side expresses the removing of $1$ and adding of $x^n$ instead. Now do some rearrangement:

\begin{align}
(1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})+(x^n-1) &= x\cdot (1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})\\
x^n-1 &= x\cdot (1+x+\dots+x^{n-1}) - (1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})\\
x^n-1 &= (x - 1)\cdot (1+x+\dots+x^{n-1}).\\
\end{align}

This already looks like the identity you are looking for, with the special assumption $a=1$. Lets generalize:

\begin{align}
x^n-a^n &= a^n\left(\left(\frac xa\right)^n-1\right)\\
&\overset{(*)}= a^n\left(\frac xa-1\right)\left(1+\frac xa+\left(\frac xa\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\frac xa\right)^{n-1}\right) \\
&= a\left(\frac xa-1\right) \cdot a^{n-1}\left(1+\frac xa+\left(\frac xa\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\frac xa\right)^{n-1}\right) \\
&=(x-a)(a^{n-1}+ x a^{n-2} +\cdots x^{n-2}a + x^{n-1}).
\end{align}

In step $(*)$ I used the special case and $x\mapsto \frac xa$ to expand the latter term.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are asking "How does someone come up with this factorization of $a^n-b^n$"?

If so, I would say the answer is: observation of patterns, guessing at generalizations, and proof. This is what mathematicians do.

Start with what we all know and maybe even discover for ourselves: 
$$a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$$
Next, take a harder one, but one which is still not too hard to know and perhaps discover: 
$$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)
$$

Next, try to observe a pattern. The first factor is $a-b$ for both of these. Then guess at a generalization: could there factorizations of similar form
$$a^4 - b^4 = (a-b)(\text{some factor?})
$$
$$a^5 - b^5 = (a-b)(\text{some different factor?})
$$
and in general
$$a^n - b^n = (a-b)(\text{some still different factor, but fitting some general pattern?})
$$
That's a very nice guess, but it's not yet completely mathematical until we can figure out a pattern for the second factor.

There are a couple of ways to proceed from here. One is to try to guess at a pattern for the second factor, and see if one can prove that this pattern is true in general. Each term of the second factor has degree $2$, the coefficient is $1$, and the pattern of exponents is to decrease the $a$-exponent one at a time and increase the $b$-exponent one at a time: $a^2 b^0 + a^1 b^1 + a^0b^2$. Could it be possible that the second factor of the $a^4 - b^4$ factorization is $a^3 b^0 + a^2 b^1 + a^1 b^2 + a^0 b^3$, or in short 
$$a^3 + a^2 b + a b^2 + b^3
$$ 
And then the completely general pattern would be 
$$a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} b + ... + a b^{n-2} + b^{n-1}
$$ 
If so, perhaps it can be proved by induction. This is exactly what the other answers show.

Another way to proceed is to use the original guess that $a-b$ is the first factor, and then use long division of polynomials to find the second factor. That works too.

Answer (score 1):

This is long division of polynomials. It essentially follows the same procedure of normal long division, where you divide the first term into the current term, distribute, and then subtract.

https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-division-long.html

Since the answer was too short, I'll try to expand on it a bit.

We want to find $x-a\overline{)x^n - a^n}$

1. x divided into $x^n$ is $x^{n-1}$
2. $x^{n-1}$ is then distributed over (x-a): $x^{n-1}(x-a) = x^n-ax^{n-1}$
3. Subtract: $x^n-a^n-(x^n-ax^{n-1}) = ax^{n-1}-a^n$

Repeat.

$x-a\overline{)ax^{n-1}-a^n}$

1. x divided into $ax^{n-1}$ gives us $ax^{n-1}$
2. $ax^{n-1}$ is then distributed over (x-a): $ax^{n-1}(x-a)=ax^{n-1}-a^2x^{n-1}$
3. Subtract: $ax^{n-1}-a^n-(ax^{n-1}-a^2x^{n-1})=a^2x^{n-1}-a^n$

From this we can see that the power of a will increase by one each time, and the power of x will decrease by one, until we get to $a^n$.

So we have $x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2} + ... + xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1}$

Comment: What? Not detailed enough?

Comment: Not my downvote but it's likely because answers where the bulk or important part of the answer is contained in a link are generally frowned upon here.  Probably better/safer to leave such things as comments.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{n}-a^{n}=\\x^{n}-a^{n}-a^{1}x^{n-1}+a^{1}x^{n-1}=\\
x^{n}-a^{1}x^{n-1}+a^{1}x^{n-1}-a^{n}=x^{n-1}(x-a)+a(x^{n-1}-a^{n-1})\\$$now do like this again 
$$x^{n-1}(x-a)+a(x^{n-1}-ax^{n-2}+ax^{n-2}-a^{n-1})\\
x^{n-1}(x-a)+a(x^{n-2}(x-a)+a(x^{n-2}-a^{n-2}))=\\
$$factor from $x-a$
$$(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a^{1})+a^2(x^{n-2}-a^{n-2})=\\
(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a^{1})+a^2(x^{n-2}-ax^{n-3}+ax^{n-3}-a^{n-2})=\\
(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a^{1})+a^2(x^{n-3}(x-a)+a(x^{n-3}-a^{n-3}))$$
factor from $x-a$
$$(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a^{1}+x^{n-3}a^{2})+a(x^{n-3}-a^{n-3})\\
(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a^{1}+x^{n-3}a^)+a^3(x^{n-3}-ax^{n-4}+ax^{n-4}-a^{n-3})\\
(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a^{1}+x^{n-3}a^{2}+x^{n-4}a^{3})+a^3(x^{n-3}-a^{n-3})\\$$ ans so on 
$$(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a^{1}+x^{n-3}a^{2}+x^{n-4}a^{3}+x^{n-4}a^3+...+x^1a^{n-2}+...+a^{n-1})$$

Answer (score 1):

The factorisation of $x^n-a^n$ is a high-school identity, derived  from the factorisation
$$1-u^n=(1-u)(1+u+u^2+\dots+u^{n-1})\tag{1}$$
which is proved by a simple induction (it is one of the best examples to make understand induction):

- First $(1)$ is true for $n=1$ or $2$.
- Second, suppose it is true for some $n\ge 1$. Then
  \begin{align}
  1-u^{n+1}&=(1-u^n)+(u^n-u^{n+1})=(1-u)(1+u+u^2+\dots+u^{n-1})+u^n(1-u)\\&=(1-u)(1+u+u^2+\dots+u^{n-1}+u^n),
  \end{align}
  which ends the inductive step.

For the formula in case, set $u=\dfrac ax\enspace(\Leftrightarrow ux=a)$, and use $(1)$:
\begin{align}
x^n-a^n&=x^n(1-u^n)=x(1-u)x^{n-1}(1+u+u^2+\dots+u^{n-1})\\
&=(x-xu)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}xu+x^{n-3}x^2u^2+\dots+x^{n-1}u^{n-1}\\
&=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+x^{n-3}a^2+\dots+a^{n-1})
\end{align}

Note that $(1)$, for $n=1$, can be written as the formula for the sum of the $n$ first terms of the *geometric series*:
$$1+u+u^2+\dots+u^n=\frac{1-u^{n+1}}{1-u}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $S=x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+\dots+a^{n-2}x+a^{n-1}$. Then
\begin{alignat}{30}
xS&=x^n&{}+{}&ax^{n-1}&{}+{}&a^2x^{n-2}&{}+{}&\!\dotsb&{}+{}&a^{n-2}x^2&{}+{}&a^{n-1}x \\
aS&=&&ax^{n-1}&{}+{}&a^2x^{n-2}&{}+{}&\!\dotsb&{}+{}&a^{n-2}x^2&{}+{}&a^{n-1}x+a^n
\end{alignat}
Subtracting gives
$$
xS-aS=x^n-a^n
$$
so, for $x\ne a$,
$$
S=\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}
$$
When $n$ is a positive rational, do a change of variables. If $n=p/q$, set $x=y^q$ and $a=b^q$, so
$$
\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=
\frac{y^p-b^p}{y^q-b^q}=
\frac{y^{p-1}+by^{p-2}+\dots+yb^{p-2}+b^{p-1}}
     {y^{q-1}+by^{q-2}+\dots+yb^{q-2}+b^{q-1}}
$$
after cancelling $y-b$ on top and bottom. For $y=b$, we get
$$
\frac{pb^{p-1}}{qb^{q-1}}=\frac{p}{q}b^{(p-1)-(q-1)}=na^{n-1}
$$
because $b=a^{1/q}$ and
$$
\frac{(p-1)-(q-1)}{q}=\frac{p}{q}-1=n-1
$$